# Allelic form counts and deleting homozygous lines

Tags: python

I have a file like this,

```
bob     NULL    0   A   A   G   G   G   G   G
tom     NULL    0   A   A   A   A   A   A   A
sara    NULL    0   C   C   C   C   T   T   T
jane    NULL    0   failed  failed  failed  failed  failed  failed  failed
```

I need to count A/C,C/A,A/T,T/A,A/G,G/A,C/G,G/C,C/T,T/C,T/G,G/T and delete all homozygous lines so my desired outputs looks like this,

```
bob     NULL    0   A   A   G   G   G   G   G  G/A
sara    NULL    0   C   C   C   C   T   T   T  C/T
```

This is my try,

```
fileA = open("myfile.txt",'r')
import re
#fileA.next()
lines=fileA.readlines()
for line in lines:
  new_list=re.split(r'\t+',line.strip())
  snp_name=new_list[0]
  allele=new_list[3:]
  failed_count = allele.count('failed')
  A_count = allele.count('A')
  C_count = allele.count('C')
  G_count = allele.count('G')
  T_count = allele.count('T')
 #A/C OR C/A count
  if A_count > 0:
    if C_count > 0:
      if A_count > C_count:
        new_list.append('A/C')
      else:
        new_list.append('C/A')
#A/T OR T/A count
    if T_count > 0:
      if A_count > T_count:
        new_list.append('A/T')
      else:
        new_list.append('T/A')
#A/G OR G/A count
    if G_count > 0:
      if A_count > G_count:
        new_list.append('A/G')
      else:
        new_list.append('G/A')
#C/G OR G/C count
  if C_count > 0:
     if G_count > 0:
      if C_count > G_count:
        new_list.append('C/G')
      else:
        new_list.append('G/C')
#C/T OR T/C count
    if T_count > 0:
      if C_count > T_count:
        new_list.append('C/T')
      else:
        new_list.append('T/C')
#T/G OR G/T count
  if T_count > 0:
    if G_count > 0:
      if T_count > G_count:
        new_list.append('T/G')
      else:
        new_list.append('G/T')
  r=open('allele_counts.txt', 'a')
  x='\t'.join(new_list)
  x=x+'\n'
  r.writelines(x)
fileA.close()
r.close()
```

Could you suggest me how to improve the code and delete all homozygous lines?

Comment: Why do you do `str(A_count)` and then `A_count > '0'` ?

Comment: yes, you are right. I will edit it

Comment: you can also add `elsif` instead of `if`s since you dont need to check every condition if you do an `append` (if I understood right?)

Comment: Will there always be exactly 2 different characters (`A`, `G`, `C`, `T`) in the lines that you want to work with? If not, what should the output look like for a line like `joe     NULL    0   A   A   C   C   G   G   G`?

Comment: no, there are always 2 different characters...

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably comes from how you wrote your file, you need to be sure to separate columns with actual `tabs`
your code works fine for me when I edited `myfile.txt`
the problem is that the previous list in which you were counting `'A'` was like:

```
['bob     NULL    0   A   A   G   G   G   G   G']
```

You need it to be:

```
['bob', 'NULL', '0', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G']
```

Comment: I checked my new_list, and it is a string..yes tab-delimited

Comment: when you do `print new_list` do you get the 1rst or the 2nd type ?

Comment: I get the 2nd one and the programs outputs me the right counts

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this refactor can help:

```
import re
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

# Use with so that you don't forget to close the file in the end. Also, it is
# more pythonic
with open("myfile.txt",'r') as fileA:
    with open('allele_counts.txt', 'a') as fileB:
        # The file object is in itself an iterator, so you can iterate over it
        for line in fileA:
            new_list = re.split(r'\t+',line.strip())
            allele = new_list[3:]
            failed_count = allele.count('failed')

            # Use python's counter object to do the counting
            counts = Counter(allele)
            # Get the top two most common strings. This returns a list of
            # tuples with item and its count
            top_two = counts.most_common(2)
            # We only need the item, so pluck that out from the list
            classification = '/'.join(map(itemgetter(0), top_two))

            # Add our classification to the new output list
            new_list.append(classification)
            # write to file
            fileB.write('\t'.join(new_list))
```

Comment: this script works, the only thing is that I have several other letters in the lines, but I am interested to count these 4 and. I never have ACT in the same line, it is a,always 2 letters of my interest, but there are also heterozygotes, like Y, R, K, and I am not interested to count them even if they are the most common.I hope i could explain

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to use a pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('myfile.txt', header=None, sep=" ", skipinitialspace=True)

select = ['A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'failed']

# select out all the heterozygous rows
for elem in select:
    df = df[(df.iloc[:,3:10] != elem).any(axis=1)]

# reset the index since we removed rows
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df[10] = '' # column 10 will hold the tags

# add the tag to the line in the form A/B where count('A') > count('B') for a row
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    tags = df.iloc[i, 3:10].unique().tolist()
    if sum(df.iloc[i, 3:10] == tags[0]) < sum(df.iloc[i, 3:10] == tags[1]):
        tags.reverse()
    df.iloc[i, 10] = '/'.join(tags)

df.to_csv('allele_counts.txt', sep=" ", header=False, index=False, na_rep='NULL')
```

When I run it using your myfile.txt, I get the following allel_counts.txt:

```
bob NULL 0 A A G G G G G G/A
sara NULL 0 C C C C T T T C/T
```